# Construct() must be an instance

Tags: php, zend-framework, web-applications, zend-framework2

I'm following the [ZF2 Manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html) and I'm facing this error:

"Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Album\Model\AlbumTable::__construct() must be an instance of Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway, instance of Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter given, called in /var/www/CommunicationApp/module/Album/Module.php on line 33 and defined in /var/www/CommunicationApp/module/Album/src/Album/Model/AlbumTable.php on line 11"

I don't know what I'm missing, because it's exactly the same as the tutorial.

```
<?php

namespace Album\Model;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class AlbumTable
{
 protected $tableGateway;

 public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
 {
     $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
 }

 public function fetchAll()
 {
     $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
     return $resultSet;
 }

 public function getAlbum($id)
 {
     $id  = (int) $id;
     $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('id' => $id));
     $row = $rowset->current();
     if (!$row) {
         throw new \Exception("Could not find row $id");
     }
     return $row;
 }

 public function saveAlbum(Album $album)
 {
     $data = array(
         'artist' => $album->artist,
         'title'  => $album->title,
     );

     $id = (int) $album->id;
     if ($id == 0) {
         $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
     } else {
         if ($this->getAlbum($id)) {
             $this->tableGateway->update($data, array('id' => $id));
         } else {
             throw new \Exception('Album id does not exist');
         }
     }
 }

 public function deleteAlbum($id)
 {
     $this->tableGateway->delete(array('id' => (int) $id));
 }
 }
```

Module.php:

```
<?php
namespace Album;
use Album\Model\AlbumTable;


class Module
{
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
        ),
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
}

public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}

public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Album\Model\AlbumTable' =>  function($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $table     = new AlbumTable($dbAdapter);
                return $table;
            },
        ),
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass TableGetway to AlbumTable. change Module.php and replace getServiceConfig with:

```
 public function getServiceConfig()
 {
     return array(
         'factories' => array(
             'Album\Model\AlbumTable' =>  function($sm) {
                 $tableGateway = $sm->get('AlbumTableGateway');
                 $table = new AlbumTable($tableGateway);
                 return $table;
             },
             'AlbumTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                 $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                 $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                 $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
                 return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
             },
         ),
     );
 }
```